# Is there any difference between "invite to" and "invite for"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences, prepositions

Is there any difference between *invite to* and *invite for* in terms of usage and meaning?

For example: invite someone ***to*** lunch, dinner, a party, or a meeting but invite them ***for*** a drink or a meal

Answer (score 9):

You're invited to a specific event, and you're invited for actions, objects, or activities that will be present at said event.

You're invited to a party, you're invited for cake and ice-cream.

Comment: In some cases, both will do: _invited to lunch_ and _invited for lunch_.